# Github Actions npm ENOENT error when building app

Tags: npm, github-actions

We have set up a deployment process for our Nuxt 3 website and the Github Action goes in error when it tries to build the app.

Error:

```
> build
> nuxt build

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn sh
npm ERR! path /home/***/work/my-website-repo-name/my-website-repo-name
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent spawn sh ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/***/.npm/_logs/2022-11-21T11_35_50_456Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 254.
```

And the following is our yml file:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Node 16.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.x

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci --ignore-scripts

      - name: Build server
        run: npm run build

      - name: Deploying
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
          source: ".output"
          target: ${{ secrets.PATH }}
```

In the local environment there are no errors when building the app, we have also tried to set the same node version with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to find the problem: somehow it works if I remove the PATH secret from the target in the last step and I replace it with the actual server path